# How to pull new objects from Django view to implement endless scrolling?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, infinite-scroll

I have a Django app for news articles. I want to first load 6 articles and when user scrolls through them, new 6 articles get automatically loaded (twitter-style endless scrolling):

I found [this](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start.html) package but it's deprecated so I'm doing it as below.

This is the view:

```
def index(request):
    context_dict = {}

    articles = Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:6]
    context_dict['articles'] =  articles
    context_dict['title'] = "title "
    context_dict['endless_scroll_token'] = '/home/'

    return render(request, 'obj_name/index.html', context_dict)
```

This is the java-script / AJAX code:

```
  <script>
  function yHandler(){

      var wrap = document.getElementById('body_panel');
      var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight;
      var yOffset = window.pageYOffset; 
      var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;

      if(y >= contentHeight){
        var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var token = {{endless_scroll_token}};

        if(token == "/home/")
          {token = '/';}

        ourRequest.open('GET', token);
        ourRequest.send();

        ourRequest.onload = function(){
        var ourData = ourRequest.responseText;
        wrap.innerHTML += ourData

      };
    }
  }
  window.onscroll = yHandler;
</script>
```

The problem is that this way, the same 6 articles are loaded over and over. How do I pull 6 ***new*** articles each time ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's called `Pagination`

There are many ways to page data. 
You can read http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

For instance, you tell server that you want #2 page of the data. 
and you and server also need to know how many items are included in each page.  (This is PageNumberPagination in the above doc)

I strongly suggest you to look at Django rest framework because it gives you many functionality including pagination.

Comment: I'd like twitter-style endless scrolling. I edited my question.

Comment: Yeah it's the same thing, you need to ask for the new page when user scrolls down to the bottom of the page.